# iPhone 4S Accelerometer Specifications

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Can anyone help me to find  some full specifications for the accelerometer of the iPhone 4S?

I tried to search something over or inside apple.com, however, I wasn't successful.

I would like some full specifications regarding the measurements of the accelerometer: measure scale, how often do the readings refresh, mainly everything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 4S uses the STMicro STM33DH 3-axis accelerometer and the STIMicro AGDI 3-axis gyroscope. I was unable to find a specifications sheet or product page.

Sources:

- http://www.bigigloo.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/CoreMotion.pdf
- http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone-4-Teardown/3130/2

Comment: If you have used it, could you please tell me in what are they measured? From your material, I get the fact that it is measured in g (9.8 m/s^2) per second. How often is the reading of the accelerometer updated?

Comment: @Simon to be honest, I'm not sure. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

The real accelerometer model is LIS331DLH, see [this](http://www.tgdaily.com/hardware-features/50344-the-real-iphone-4-teardown) (emphasis mine)

> Of the major design wins, Infineon found itself with the transceiver (marked with 'Apple 338S0626') and the X-GOLD 61x (marked '3833') baseband processor. [However], the most notable of parts though was from **ST Micro**, who provided not only the **LIS331DLH 3-axis accelerometer (incorrectly identified as the STM33DH)** [along with] the 3-axis digital gyroscope...

The [Chipworks webpage](http://www.chipworks.com/en/technical-competitive-analysis/resources/blog/iphone-4s-teardown-a-closer-look-at-the-chips-inside/) also identified it as the LIS331DLH

The specifications for accelerometer are [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00213470.pdf).